# How to show number of dynamically added field of array. Laravel-vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm making a recipe book website and I want to add recipe steps dynamically, what I want is when the steps are added instead of the user manually adding the step number the step number is automatically added. This is what it looks right now, with adding the step number manually.

My question is can this be added dynamically while adding these steps dynamically with the plus button starting with step 1. How can I accomplish this?

[image]

This is the code I have right now for this section

```
<el-form ref="form" :model="form" :rules="rules">
    <el-row>
        <div class="btn-link-plus action-button" @click="addStep()">
            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </div>
    </el-row>

    <div v-for="(item, index) in steps" :key="index">
        <el-card shadow="never" class="step-card">
            <el-row :gutter="10">
                <el-col :span="12">
                    <el-form-item label="Step Number" prop="num">
                        <el-input-number style="width: 100%" controls-position="right"
                            v-model="item.num"></el-input-number>
                    </el-form-item>
                </el-col>
                <el-col :span="12">
                    <el-form-item label="Duration" prop="duration">
                        <el-input-number style="width: 100%" controls-position="right"
                            v-model="item.duration"></el-input-number>
                    </el-form-item>
                </el-col>
            </el-row>
            <el-row>
                <el-form-item label="Instructions" prop="instructions">
                    <el-input type="textarea" v-model="item.instructions"></el-input>
                </el-form-item>
            </el-row>
            <el-row class="fa-pull-right">
                <div class="btn-link-delete action-button" @click="removeStep(index)">
                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
                </div>
            </el-row>
        </el-card>
    </div>
</el-form>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you need to automatically generate step numbers instead of manually entering numbers?

Comment: @sugars yes, that's what I mean

Comment: The `index` in `v-for` is the number you want, you can use it directly.

Comment: @sugars What about when I need to save those step numbers in the controller?

Comment: The step index in the `this.steps` is what you want, loop `this.steps` and save index when you click the save button.